# What is difference between tf.FIFOQueue and data_flow_ops.StagingArea?

Tags: tensorflow

Why is the StaingArea better than the performance of FIFOQueue? What's the difference in principle as they provide similar API and function.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models.

Queues make use of Python threads and so have some bottlenecks, and don't have a great CPU to GPU transfer story. StagingArea addresses those issues.

Eventually [tf.contrib.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset) (not queues) will have a better API for StagingArea-like performance. In the meantime, there is some tradeoff between ease of use and performance.

Comment: Does it mean that Dataset API will replace StagingArea? Or Dataset API and StagingArea can be used collaboratively?

Comment: The hope is that the Dataset API will do the staging for you automatically.